# PHP Regex start with a letter

Tags: php, regex

How can I check if the input is C12345 ( Capital letter "C" followed by 5 numbers (total 6 digits)

I have this code

```
$val = "/^\d\d\d\d\d\d$/";
    if (! preg_match($val, $source)) {
        $error_msg .= "<p>your source must be 6 digits long</p>";
    }       


    $secval = "/^\"C\"\d\d\d\d\d$/";
    if (! preg_match($secval, $source)) {
        $error_msg .= "<p>source must be 6 digits long and start with an "S"</p>";
    }
```

Comment: (1) What is the problem with what you've done?  (2) Why do you need the quotes around `C` in your pattern?

Comment: Yes I just need to delete the quote, sorry Im new with regexp, php, and js. thanks for the comment

Comment: If you're new to regex, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great primer. If you're not, it's a great reference. Even shows the little differences between regex engines.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
^[A-Z]\d{5}$
```

Single letter, A through Z followed by 5 digits

If the first letter must be C, use

```
^C\d{5}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
^C\d{5}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/h9LBxIaC4Po_N6_m)

If you want any other character, use the character set [A-Z], which means, any character from capital A to Z

```
^[A-Z]\d{5}$
```